# Trying to understand behavior of Python multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

So I have a function in which the parent process creates suppose two child processes since there are two schemas.

```
def data_push_main():
  schema_name_list = schema_name.split(",")
  pool = mp.Pool(processes=len(schema_name_list))
  try:
    for schema_name in schema_name_list:
      pool.apply_async(data_push_per_schema, (config, schema_name))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
  except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    pool.terminate()
    pool.join()
    logger.exception("Keyboard interrupt occured")
  except Exception as e:
    pool.terminate()
    pool.join()
```

Now when I start running the program the `ps -ef | grep` output is like

```
as   3448  3209  1 11:47 pts/2    00:00:01 /usr/bin/python2.6 /export/app/i001/bin/data-push.pex
as   3464  3448 14 11:47 pts/2    00:00:15 /usr/bin/python2.6 /export/app/i001/bin/data-push.pex

as   3465  3448  9 11:47 pts/2    00:00:10 /usr/bin/python2.6 /export/app/i001/bin/data-push.pex
```

When I kill one of the child process say 3464 (using `kill -9`) the whole thing runs fine.

When I kill the parent process i.e. 3448 it makes 3465 the parent. Is this expected behavior. Should the except block have been called and pool should have been terminated? Also what happens when this child process now terminates?

**observation:** The last process printed

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 71, in worker
    put((job, i, result))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 366, in put
    return send(obj)
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: Ideally the process wouldn't be abruptly murdered but this is still an interesting question...

Comment: I'd try sending different signals. Signal 9 that you're using (`SIGKILL`) can't be handled by the process in any way. The OS just stops the process immediately. Try sending signal 15 (`SIGTERM`) or 2 (`SIGINT`) instead and you may have better luck writing code to handle it.

Comment: Understood. Let me try that @Blckknght